# How do I mimic the excel "insert Comment" in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I admire the excel "insert comments" cell option. I would like to reproduce this in my datagridview in .net 2.0 using c#. Could somebody give me an idea as to the approch I should take on creating the edit box.

Thanks
c# winforms, .net 2.0

Comment: There's two challenges here:
1. How do you display the comment
2. How do you serialize and deserialize the comment?

Storing the "location" of the comment can be tricky if your datagridview is being bound to a variety of different data sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple overview would be to create a form that looks like the insert dialog from Excel, and implement the various options (shifting cells up/down, inserting a new row/column).

You will need to add a context menu strip to the datagridview with a insert menu item, and when that is clicked have your insert dialog pop up.